# Unable to open remote XML file using fopen(). What all permission i need to set in server or what parameters i need to set in fopen() function.?

Tags: php, fopen, file-permissions

I am trying to open an XML file in remote server through fopen() function.
I have two remote servers and the file permission of the xml is set to 777 in both servers.
i am able to open the xml from one server , but not from other. Both files can be opened in browser.

What all permission i need to set or what parameters i need to set in fopen() function.?

this is the function

```
function getFileData($ProjectName)
{
    $file = fopen($ProjectName, "r") or exit("Unable to open File! ".$ProjectName);
    $fileContent="";
        while(!feof($file))
          {
         $fileContent.=fgets($file);
          }
    fclose($file);
    echo $fileContent;
}

getFileData('http://serverA.com/myxml.xml'); // gives the content
getFileData('http://serverB.com/myxml.xml'); // gives the error fopen(http:/serverB.com/myxml.xml) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have one / after http: in the last two lines - but I doubt that's the problem. Can you open the file in the browser?

Perhaps try using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) . It does the same as your function, except it's ready made and fully tested by the PHP guys.

Comment: that was a typing mistake,, i have corrected that. i am using "http://" . yes i try with the "file_get_contents ()" same error is getting. Do i need to any othe params with that function

Comment: Check the documentaiton for file_get_contents (click the link) regarding parameters for it.

Comment: Perhaps your webserver running your PHP code is having trouble connecting to your serverB.com. Can you retrieve other files from serverB.com?

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be http://server and not http:/server.

Comment: Maybe this url could help you: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx

Comment: If the URL responds with a 1xx, 4xx, or 5xx status code, you will get a "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!", followed by the HTTP status response. Same goes for file_get_contents($url)... Can you open second url with your browser?

Comment: how can i check the url response status code..? yes i can open both in browser.. What file permission need to set in the server.?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the visible problem with URL, also check what is the value for `allow_url_fopen` set in your php.ini, if you can open file from one server but not from other server this may be correctly set for you, did you check about timeouts?

Comment: i try with the "file_get_contents ()" same error is getting. Do i need to any othe params with that function

Comment: So what you are saying is it works for one URL but fails for another one, try switching urls or try fetching only one URL that is failing

Comment: yes.. the second one is failing... but i can open it in browser.. What file permission need to set.?