# PHP fopen not working when try to look at a file using ftp

Tags: php, linux

I have Ubuntu installed on an Odroid. I need this box to connect to a remote website to check a .txt file. I have used the code below on two remote servers and I get the result I need. However, running the code on the odroid, I get "Unable to open file!".

I am sure this must be something to do with the PHP settings but I am now at a loss as to what it could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$filename = "ftp://username:password@80.1.1.1/version.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$contents = fgets($handle);
echo "Version = " . $contents . "<br>";

fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open file by providing document root path with filename.

```
$rootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$filename = $rootPath.'version.txt';
```

Comment: Not quite doing what I expected. That gives me access to the same file on the Odriod box. I need access to the file on a remote server. probably using ftp.

Comment: It looks vey similar to this problem too.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938254/unable-to-open-remote-xml-file-using-fopen-what-all-permission-i-need-to-set